# Getting DCPError when trying to solve Dual form of SVM using CVXPY

Tags: python, svm, cvxpy, cvxopt, cvx

I am trying to create a SVM using cvxpy, by solving its Dual form

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

DIM = 2
NUM = 50
#COLORS = ['red', 'blue']
M1 = np.ones((DIM,))
M2 = 2 * np.ones((DIM,))
C1 = np.diag(0.3 * np.ones((DIM,)))
C2 = np.diag(0.2 * np.ones((DIM,)))

def generate_gaussian(m, c, num):
     return np.random.multivariate_normal(m, c, num)

NUM = 50
x1 = generate_gaussian(M1, C1, NUM)
y1 = np.ones((x1.shape[0],))
x2 = generate_gaussian(M2, C2, NUM)
y2 = -np.ones((x2.shape[0],))
# join
x = np.concatenate((x1, x2), axis = 0)
y = np.concatenate((y1, y2), axis = 0)
print('x {} y {}'.format(x.shape, y.shape))

alphas = cp.Variable(2*NUM)
Cd = cp.Parameter()
Cd.value = 0.95

alphas_constraint_1 = [alphas[i] >=0 for i in range(2*NUM)]
alphas_constraint_2 = [alphas[i] <= Cd for i in range(2*NUM)]
alpha_y_constraint = [alphas@y.T == 0]

constraints = alphas_constraint_1 + alphas_constraint_2 + alpha_y_constraint

K = y[:,None]*x
K = np.dot(K,K.T)

objective_dual = cp.Minimize(-cp.sum(alphas)+cp.quad_form(alphas,K))

prob_dual = cp.Problem(objective_dual,constraints)
prob_dual.solve()
```

When I run `prob_dual.solve()` I get this error

```
DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
QuadForm(var14498, [[ 2.64314065  3.52503472  3.06058033 ... -4.66774474 
-4.06204535
 -4.25545758]
 [ 3.52503472  4.70705211  4.09996823 ... -6.26760728 -5.41784971
  -5.71519635]
 [ 3.06058033  4.09996823  3.60040302 ... -5.53652152 -4.70508757
  -5.05117747]
 ...
 [-4.66774474 -6.26760728 -5.53652152 ...  8.54985838  7.17702844
   7.80325227]
 [-4.06204535 -5.41784971 -4.70508757 ...  7.17702844  6.24269435
   6.5432026 ]
 [-4.25545758 -5.71519635 -5.05117747 ...  7.80325227  6.5432026
   7.12207384]])
```

How can the Dual form of SVM not be a convex problem?
Where is the error? Can't figure it out.

I ran this piece of code:

```
expr1 = alphas.T@alphas
expr2 = cp.quad_form(alphas,K)
print(expr1.curvature, expr1.sign, expr1.is_dcp())
print(expr2.curvature, expr2.sign, expr2.is_dcp())
```

And I got the same output for both

```
UNKNOWN UNKNOWN False
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you provide code that fully reproduces what you believe to be an error. In particular, the code snippet you've given doesn't run. (What's y? What's x?)

Comment: @AkshayAgrawal I have edited the code part. I have provided the full code. The `K` seems to be the problem here.

Comment: But can't figure out why the issue is arising here

Comment: Posting the issue thread on github here : https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/962